# Can I change the location of my Banner in cooperative?

Tags: diablo-iii

I as playing Diablo 3 in cooperative mode, when I notice the ability to teleport to other players in my party if I clicked on their banner (if you haven't done this yet, do it - it rewards you with an achievement).

I then noticed, if I had to teleport back to the town for clearing out my inventory, I could then just click on their banner to teleport back to them (given that we were relatively close to each other prior).

This then triggered my question: **Is it possible to move or place your banner some where else in the world other than the town or safe location?** (example: if we were in a dungeon and wanted to return specifically to one spot [ such as a fork in the path ] and there was not a teleporting pad nearby or found yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>G</kbd> you can place your banner to a desired location, in early versions of beta it served exactly the purpose you mentioned...

Unfortunately they removed it since it was too abused, now it is used just to show others your banner and to "ping" your allies on the map.